# Cannot use highest resolution supported by external monitor

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution

Specification first:

- Dell Inspiron 7577
- Monitor Iiyama XUB2792QSU
- Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS

Monitor supports 2560x1440 resolution, but when I choose it, it loses signal. Monitor is connected with HDMI cable. I can choose second resolution in list and it works fine. I tried both nouveau and nvidia drivers - same behaviour.

Things you may be interesed in:

```
$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 4480 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93    48.03  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 connected 2560x1440+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95*+
   2048x1280     59.99  
   1920x1200     59.95  
   1920x1080     60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.88  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02  
   1440x900      59.90  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  

$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 05)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Skylake PCIe Controller (x16) (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 591b (rev 04)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Skylake Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 05)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 31)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 31)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #6 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)
3b:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
3c:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8265 / 8275 (rev 78)
```

As you can see resolution is detected, but "no signal" appears on monitor when I select it. Desktop is extended properly, but obviously I cannot see cursor when I move it to another display.

Comment: Having the exact same behavior on my MSI GS65 with a Dell 22inch display. Did you ever figure this out @unhit

Comment: Unfortunately, no. My colleague has exact same equipment and claims it's working fine. Except he is using Linux Mint, but I don't have time or will to cross check what is the problem. I'm getting used to lower resolution... disappointing.

Comment: I'm pretty ready to launch my laptop into the sun.

Comment: are you using gdm3 or lightdm? I was initially using gdm3, but it didn't recognize the external monitor at all, and I was able to fix the problem entirely (ie use the highest resolution) by switching to lightdm. That worked for about a day, until the problem you're having started affecting me. So, I'm considering uninstalling and reinstalling lightdm....

Comment: I'm using gdm3, but I checked lightdm a moment ago. Same problem.

Comment: Bah, sorry to get your hopes up, even briefly. Well, if you find a solution, do post about it here, and I'll do the same.